# Laravel5 eloquent query returns nothing, but raw query does?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

**Update** According to:

```
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    $last_query = end($queries);

    var_dump($queries);
```

Laravel isn't running any queries: `array(0) {}`

**Original post**

I've got this method (please ignore all the comments - I'm debugging):

```
public function runForResultSet(){
    $params = [];

    $query = Recipient::with('recipientTags', 'contactDetails', 'recipientTags.tagGroups');
    foreach($this->segmentCriteria as $criteria){
        $parts = explode('.', $criteria['field']);
        $fieldObject = SegmentTableWhiteListFields::where('field', '=', $parts[1])->get();
        foreach($fieldObject as $whiteList){
            $params[0] = [$criteria->value];
            $query->whereRaw(\DatabaseHelper::generateOperationAsString($whiteList, $parts, $criteria), $params[0]);
        }
    }

    $collection = $query->get();
    // $collection = $collection->filter(
    //  function($response) {
    //      $returnValues = [];
    //      foreach($response->getRelations()['recipientTags'] as $recipientTags){
    //          foreach($this->segmentRecipientTagGroupCriteria as $criteria){
    //              // return only results that match our segment criterias - both tag group name
    //              // and tag group ids
    //              $returnValues[] = ((DatabaseHelper::determineAndRunOperation($recipientTags->name, $criteria->operator, $criteria->value))
    //                  && $recipientTags->recipient_tag_group_id == $criteria->recipient_tag_group_id);
    //
    //          }
    //      }
    //      return count(array_keys($returnValues, true)) == count($returnValues);
    //  }
    // );

    // return the response
    return response()->json($collection, \ApiResponse::$STATUS_OK);
}
```

The generateOperationAsString method:

```
public static function generateOperationAsString($whiteList, $parts, $criteria){
    switch($whiteList->datatype){
      case "VARCHAR":
      case "TEXT":
        switch(strtoupper($criteria->operator)){
          case "IS NULL":
          case "IS NOT NULL":
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator;
          break;
          default:
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator . " ?";
        }
        break;

      case "INT":
      case "DOUBLE":
      case "FLOAT":
      case "REAL":
        switch(strtoupper($criteria->operator)){
          case "IS NULL":
          case "IS NOT NULL":
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator;
          break;
          default:
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator . " ?";
        }
        break;

      // Possibly don't need to separate these, but...
      case "TIMESTAMP":
      case "DATETIME":
        switch(strtoupper($criteria->operator)){
          case "IS NULL":
          case "IS NOT NULL":
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator;
          break;
          default:
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator . " ?";
        }
        break;

      case "DATE":
        switch(strtoupper($criteria->operator)){
          case "IS NULL":
          case "IS NOT NULL":
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator;
          break;
          default:
            return "`".$parts[1] . "` " . $criteria->operator . " ?";
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

And the overall sql it generates is (echo'd from $query):

```
select * from `recipients` where `last_visit` is not null
```

The trouble is that eloquent returns zero rows. Whereas the query itself returns over 50 (?!) when run in a putty session. And I've got no idea why eloquent doesn't find these rows? I've read some chatter that `whereRaw` is a little hit and miss, but can't find any concrete evidence to support that. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. In specific instances my `$criteria->value` was empty, specifically when building dynamic `IS NULL` queries, where values weren't applicable. In this scenario `whereRaw` wasn't running as the parameters passed where null/empty (an error message would've been helpful!). I changed the code above to:

```
// Need to check for empty value as laravel's whereRaw will not run if the provided
// params are null/empty - In which case we need to use whereRaw without params.
if(!empty($criteria->value)){
    $query->whereRaw(\DatabaseHelper::generateOperationAsString($whiteList, $parts, $criteria), $params[0]);
}else{
    $query->whereRaw(\DatabaseHelper::generateOperationAsString($whiteList, $parts, $criteria));
}
```